# CakePHP: How can redirect to a new web page with html anchor <a>... </a>?

Tags: php, cakephp, hyperlink, cakephp-1.3, anchor

The comment form =>

```
echo $this->Form->create('Comment',array('url'=>array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' =>'add', $listposts['Post']['id']) ) );

echo $this->Form->input('post_id',array('type'=>'hidden','style'=>'width:30%','value'=>$listposts['Post']['id']));  
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('style'=>'width:30%'));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('style'=>'width:30%'));   
echo $this->Form->input('body',array('rows'=>'5'));

echo $this->Form->end('Comment');
```

In the body field of the comment form if i type like this =>

```
<a href="www.google.com"> google </a>
```

I get a link "google" in that web page but if i click that link it doesn't redirect to www.google.com. Why doesn't redirect ?

If i hover that link i see =>

```
http://www.mysite.com/posts/view/www.google.com
```

How can i redirect to www.google.com clicking that link ?

Comment: Oh my... that's probably a perfect example why Chrome's (and Firefox 7's) "let's hide http:// in the address bar" feature is a horrible thing. Looks like we have somebody who thinks http:// is optional just because he doesn't have to enter it in the browser (and hey, it's not even shown!!!11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the url "http://www.google.com". Because there's no protocol specifier it interprets the href field as a relative link instead of a link to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html help of Cakephp:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('google', 'http://www.google.com'); ?>
```